# Concatenate variables which appear in the GROUP BY statement

Tags: sql, concatenation

In a database I have the dimensions of an item stored as separate columns (i.e. Height and Width). I want to pull a report grouping by the two size dimensions and possibly concatenate them in the results.

For instance on the result I would like to have in the first column the dimension showed as "300x250".

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: `width+ 'x' + height`

Comment: Thanks for the tip OracleUser! The following code works perfectly: SELECT CAST(width AS varchar) + 'x' + CAST(height AS varchar) AS 'Dimension'

Comment: Cool, I assumed as there is 'x' the '+' will be overloaded for String by default.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
SELECT CONCAT(width, 'x', height) AS dimensions FROM table GROUP BY width, height
```

Comment: Apparently the CONCAT function is not a built-in function in SQL Server 2008 R2: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Yeah, you are correct. You can use the '+' operator to concatenate strings in SQL Server instead of concat(). So, the above statement would be: `SELECT CAST(width AS varchar) + 'x' + CAST(height AS varchar) AS dimensions FROM Table GROUP BY width, height`